# Is this pointer code legal on 64-bit computers

Tags: c, pointers, memory, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I plan to use memory across two pointers. Let's call them pointer1 and pointer2. Each pointer will be connected to its own share of memory as defined by block1 and block2 respectively.

I think this way works for all systems (both 32 and 64 bit):

```
char block1[100000];
char *pointer1=block1;
char block2[100000];
char *pointer2=block2;
```

However I think a faster way would be to use this code:

```
char block[200000];
char *pointer1=block;
char *pointer2=block+100000;
```

My question is would the last line of the last code fragment be compatible with 64-bit architecture?

Comment: Firsly, there's no real difference between the two. Secondly, where does the matter of "64-bit architecture" even come from? What specific detail of "64-bit architecture" made you to ask the question? Without additional clarification, your question sound like "Will this work on Mondays?".

Comment: No offence, but: if you have to ask, you should definitively read about pointer arithmetics. Because if you knew, you could answer this on your own.

Comment: I would use `pointer1` instead of `block` in the last line of the second snippet.

Comment: `64-bit architecture`  what will this make any difference in this matter?

Comment: The second block would work fine... and in code review, you would be told to stop trying to get fancy without any benefit - it's not faster (and even if it was, you couldn't measure the difference using any reasonably useful timing resolution).

Comment: Well, there will be a difference, since in the first case the two blocks are not contiguous, so some pointer arithmetic crossing the border could lead to UB..

Comment: I understand pointer arithmetics but sometimes trying to convert 32-bit code to 64-bit compatible code can be a nightmare. There's more issues here with porting code: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/

Comment: As others stated, that has nothing to do with 16/32/64 or 19 bit architectures. The conversion issues come from relying on implementation specific or even undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mike Nice link, but which part of it is related to the code presented?

Comment: I initially thought `char *pointer2=block+100000;` would cause an out of bounds error if the value of block or the value of pointer2 exceeds 4GB?

Comment: @Mike just keep in mind that in first case `pointer2` is pointing to the starting address of memory of 10000 bytes represented by `block2`. However, in case-2 `pointer2` is just pointing to the byte which is `100000` after the starting address of `block1`

Comment: @Mike: Since the value of `block+100000` points inside an existing array object `block`, it cannot possibly "exceed" anything. A more likely issue would be the compiler refusing to accept the declaration of `block` for being "too large". But this is more likely to be an issue of 32-bit platform than on 64-bit platform. Which is why your reference to potential issues on 64-bit platforms specifically is so puzzling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address space of a 32-bit architecture is of 2**32 = 4294967296. For a 64-bit is 18446744073709551616. I think you will be ok. THe compiler should handle it on its own. For your use case, it is just plain simple pointer arithmetics that is still in the address space.

Comment: I'll take your word on it. So far my code executes well on 32 and 64 bit platforms, although its been only running on the 64-bit platform for a few hours. I'll check later to see if I end up with a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is set up a memory pool in its most basic form.  Your example uses char arrays and pointers, so you are unlikely to get unwanted results; however if your second pointer was , for instance, `long *` (with proper casting) you would get differences in alignment which could cause significantly slower code unless you take special precautions to align them manually (using hex values instead of decimal for offsets makes this a bit more obvious)

So in a more complex scenario, it *would* matter because `long` may need to be aligned to 8 bytes or 4.

I apologize for going a bit beyond the scope of the question, but I didn't want someone mistakenly extrapolating what is fine for `char` to mixed types onto a `char[]`